# JUnit and Cobertura

Tags: java, junit, cobertura

I've written a test case for a class that implements an interface. Basically I am testing the overridden methods and test passes. On the Cobertura report `public class ROSConsumerConnectorRequest implements IConnectorRequest<ROSNotificationRequest>` shows red.

Class under test:

```
public class ROSConsumerConnectorRequest implements IConnectorRequest<ROSNotificationRequest>
```

JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ROSConsumerConnectorRequest req = new ROSConsumerConnectorRequest();
    ROSNotificationRecipient recipient = new ROSNotificationRecipient();
    ROSNotificationRequest request = new ROSNotificationRequest();
    req.setRecipient( recipient );
    req.setRequest( request );

    assertTrue( req instanceof IConnectorRequest );
    assertEquals( request, req.getRequest() );
    assertEquals( recipient, req.getRecipient() );
}
```

Only the above mentioned line shows in a red. How can I cover that line?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'd want to put IConnectorRequest req = new ROSConsumerConnectorRequest(); on the left side rather than ROSConsumerConnectorRequest req = new ROSConsumerConnectorRequest();

Comment: The problem is I won't be able to invoke setRecipient and setRequest methods with the dot operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the methods for the setters protected and simply put in the same package but in a different directory structure (E.g. Test) That's what I do to test methods and not publicly scoped.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Dale.

Comment: Awesome.  Glad that helped!